# How to know Geographic location from an IP address

Tags: java, dns, geolocation, ip-address, ip-geolocation

I have created a login application in jsp/servlet in my web project and I want to know about the geographic locations of different users those access my login page. How can I know that a person is accessing my login page from where? For example: If a person is accessing a page from Canada then a record will be inserted into my database such as : IP: 20.4.9.134 and location: Canada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this:

http://freegeoip.net/xml/122.169.8.137

Or

http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=xx.xx.xx.xx

Easy call and it throws you an xml with everything you need to know

Edit: New location for geoip

Comment: how can I call this xml file in java? Can you please explain briefly

Comment: Create a URL object with correct url and parse the xml response

Answer (score 1):

try a geo ip database, like maxmind

this question lists a few possibilities: [Reputable geo-ip location Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389219/reputable-geo-ip-location-services)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DB of MaxMind (the free version):
http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity

But have in mind that geolocating by IP is never too accurate and might give huge errors especially when using GPRS/EDGE/3G mobile internet.