# Free World City/Country Database

Tags: database, country, city

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Geocode database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945706/geocode-database)

Can anyone provide a link to any free database/csv resource for world's city/country? I have found one at [maxmin site](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities) . Their country information is ok. But city information isn't good at all. as I did get several thousands city info for my country(Bangladesh), where there is only 64. So, I guess, it may have same problem with other countries as well. So, looking for a reliable source. Please let me know if you know of any. I would like to use it on my web application. Thanks.

Comment: This kind of question is off-topic for this website.

Comment: Previously asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945706/geocode-database

Comment: They didn't think it was off-topic when it was asked before.  I, for one, am glad, because I used the file indicated in the top answer on the other instance of this question, and I'd argue it's a ood thing to have on the site as it's a common need among developers.  ;-)  But I'm also voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think it was answered there properly. No answer was accepted buy the questioner and I also didn't find any completely helpful.

Comment: I suggest, you to checkout this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/turalus/openDB