# Query a website in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

Is there any way to script SSIS to reach out to a website, input data in a search field, and then return the results? I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of postal codes as it goes through the SSIS package.

Here is the website I was thinking of using: http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocode

Is this even possible? Or an easier way to do this?

And yes before anyone asks, I've been searching all day to find a solution for this and I can't come across anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* reach out and call the API via a script component (no need to make a proper DLL) in the Data Flow itself but look at it realistically.

You're performing a Lat/long lookup based on postal codes. There is a finite number of those. They aren't going to change---the center point for 65401 is *always* going to evaluate to the same value so why ask for it multiple times from a provider. Most of these free services have an upper boundary on the number of calls you can make within a timeframe so instead of doing a realtime lookup, compute all the possible values. Take your time collecting them and then store them in your local database. This may or may not violate a site's ToS by the way.

Within your Data Flow itself, add a Lookup Component and then simply query the table you created above and away it runs.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a web service call in SSIS? That is crazy talk!

Get the [geocode database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945706/geocode-database), load it into a table, then run [spacial queries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280487.aspx) against it.

MUCH faster and so easy a caveman could do it.

If you really must use a webservice call, [you can compile some C# code and install as a dll on sqlserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254956%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You can then reach out and call this code in SSIS. I would not recommend this.

Comment: That's just it, I have a table loaded with Postal Codes and lat/long already (900k records). which i got from here: http://geocoder.ca/?freedata=1 But it is missing come postal codes. So I was going to run a search to get the rest. The geocode database you linked to doesn't seem to have full postal codes, just the beginning prefix.