# Web Service in SSIS

Tags: web-services, ssis

I am trying to use a web service as part of a dataflow task in SSIS. Right now i have a script task within a data flow with a web service reference.

What the task has to ultimately do is: collect all postal codes from an inernal database > use the web service i created to get the lay/long of thos postal codes > export the lat/long to a table.

As i said before i have the scrip set up and looks to be working, but when i go to execute the package i get an `CannotCreateUserComponentException` error.

Any help on this would be awesome, or another approach to it? I am new to the web services in SSIS so this is the best solution i could come up with.

Edit:

Right now the script is accepting the postal code from an `OLE DB Source` and will ouput a string in for format of "lat,long" (presumably). The web Service was created by someone within the company and has one method called `FindCoordinates` which takes in a string value (Postal code)(which i think calls the google geocode xml, not exactly sure what he did). Here is the code that is currently in my script:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using SC_6c1b642acd544cd5b01c032b6f8dfd03.csproj.MyService;
using System.Xml;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://microsoft.com/webservices/")]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        /*
          Add your code here for preprocessing or remove if not needed
        */
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        /*
          Add your code here for postprocessing or remove if not needed
          You can set read/write variables here, for example:
          Variables.MyIntVar = 100
        */
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        String postal = Row.PostalCode;
        Service service = new Service();

        Row.LatLong = service.FindCoordinates(postal);
    }

}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Earlier question in the series http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772225/query-a-website-in-ssis

Comment: And you told me to manually lookup each lat/long i need for each postal code without a lat/long. I have over 6,000 postal codes that need lat/long co-ords. and yes id only need to do it once, once the lat/long are retrieved they would stay in that table.

Comment: My comment was merely to provide some context for others to your question. As it stands, this question is a little light on actionable details. All we know is that the packages raises the error but what the code actually is or how anything works is a mystery at the moment.

Comment: We've come up with a solution to this and it doesn't use a dataflow at all. I don't have time right now to post how we did it right now, but will update tomorrow morning when I get in from work.